# Use of Numpy to mask cells filled with a given value

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Suppose that I have a np.array of `shape` `(3,3)` that contains cells filled with 3 zeros, or with any other specified value.

```
value = 0.,0.,0.

example_array = np.array([[0.,0.,0.],[1.,2.,3.],[0.,0.,0.]])
```

I want to mask the cells that are identical to `value`, the mask should hide all the cells filled with 3 zeros (or any other specified `value`), so:

`example_array[mask]`

would return:

```
array([[1.,2.,3.]])
```

notice that the number of dimensions of the array is still the same.

I also want to use my `mask` on other arrays that have the same shape as `example_array`:

```
another_array = np.array([[5.,6.,0.],[1.,8.,3.],[9.,9.,9.]])
```

so that:

```
another_array[mask]
```

would return:

```
array([[1.,8.,3.]])
```

How should I declare the variable `mask` to produce this effect?

Comment: 1) we need more context about that problem you're actually trying to solve and 2) you probably don't need a mask, just fancy/boolean indexing (e.g., `example_array[example_array > 0]`

Comment: if you just don't need zeros you could similar to @PaulH: `example_array[example_array != 0]` which will give you `array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])`

Comment: Do you want a flat array of just the rows where values are not all 0? i.e what should  `np.array([[0., 0., 1.], [1., 2., 3.], [0., 0., 0.]]` return

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I need the rows, not a flattened array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all rows, where at least one value is `!= 0`, you must first filter the rows:

```
example_array = numpy.array([[0.,0.,0.],[1.,2.,3.],[0.,0.,0.]])
row_mask = (example_array!=0).all(axis=1)
masked_array = example_array[row_mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
example_array = np.array([[0., 0., 1.], [1., 2., 3.], [0., 0., 0.]])
example_array[np.any(example_array, axis=1)]
```

Would give you:

```
[[ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]]
```

using all:

```
example_array = np.array([[0., 0., 1.], [1., 2., 3.], [0., 0., 0.]])

print(example_array[np.all(example_array, axis=1)])
```

Would give:

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.]]
```